# VSCode c++ shows error, while it is not an error (using zmq)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, zeromq

I'm using the following code

> ```
>   std::string abctxt ="abc";
>   zmq::message_t z_out(abctxt);
> ```

I can compile and run the code, but vscode shows the error:

"no instance of constructor "zmq::message_t::message_t" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::string)C/C++(289)"

I tried a few solutions on stackoverflow, but they don't work

here is the c_pp_properties.json

> ```
> "configurations": [
>     {
>         "name": "Linux",
>         "includePath": [
>             "${workspaceFolder}/**"
>         ],
>         "defines": [],
>         "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
>         "cStandard": "c17",
>         "cppStandard": "c++17",
>         "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
>         "compilerArgs": [
>             "-lzmq",
>             "-pthread"
>         ]
>     }
> ],
> "version": 4
> ```

I am using WSL 2.0, g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, zmq version 1.71.0.0ubuntu2

Comment: Intellisense, CODAN, and other as-you-type error checkers in the various IDEs out there are best looked at as really fast compilers that are allowed to be wrong in order to provide prompt feedback. As a result, they are sometimes wrong. Usually helpful enough to keep using, though.

Comment: @user4581301 Is it possible to make them more accurate? (Possibly by asking them to look deeper in the codes)